# std::bad_alloc while using point cloud library

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

point cloud library version 1.11.1
code below was written followed some tutorials.
it's built successfully,but crashed after running.
a std::bad_alloc is thrown when debugging at

```
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("name");
```

could anyone help me?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include<pcl/point_types.h>
#include<pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

int main()
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    cloud->width = 5;
    cloud->height = 1;
    cloud->is_dense = false;
    cloud->points.resize(cloud->width * cloud->height);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); i++)
    {
        cloud->points[i].x = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].y = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].z = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }

    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("test_pcd.pcd", *cloud);
    std::cerr << "saved" << cloud->points.size() << "data points to test_pcd.pcd" << std::endl;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); i++)
        std::cerr << " " << cloud->points[i].x << " " << cloud->points[i].y << " " << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;

    const std::string name = "nb";
    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("name");
    viewer.showCloud(cloud);
    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXb5S.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using release version of pcl_visualization library in your 'debug' configuration (seen from the screenshots of the call stack).
Try to link the debug one (pcl_visualizationd.dll)